# Set working directory of a project in mono repo in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, monorepo

My project is using microservices and in one repos we have multiple applications in Azure DevOps.
For Example, we have Repos named Microservice, where we have .NetProject, AngularUI Project, and Java Project code.The structure looks like this:

[image]

While setting up the CI pipeline, I have included the path like the below:

```js
variables:
  - name: working-dir
    value: 'MicroserviceProject/AngularUI/ClientApp/'

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  paths:
    include:
      - 'MicroserviceProject/AngularUI/ClientApp/*'
```

I don't see the code of AngularUI project being checkout properly and encountering the error, that they cannot locate the package.json file.
How can I set the working directory for different projects in a repo?

Update:

I am able to locate the file but the build isnot giving me any output files.
[image]

Comment: Can you share the logs? I can't understand the issue.

Comment: I fixed the initial issue.now the file package.json is located but build is giving zero output. i have updated the question

Comment: What task did you use? Please share your complete yaml file.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me out. I resolved it. The build artifacts wasnt available as i have set the working directory. Hence I had to explicitly output the file to staging artifacts directory

Comment: @Asterix Glad to hear that! Please share your solution as an answer and mark it. This will make it easier for people who have the same question to find answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I fixed this issue:
Initially I was not sure if the working directory was set properly.Even if it was , I was not sure whether the package.json file was read properly. To check that, I added the below script to the Azure CI pipeline, for example:

```
  inputs:
targetType: 'inline'
script: dir
  $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

displayName: 'Check'

This showed me that after building , the artifacts are not stored anywhere. hence I had to explicitly mention the outputpath. For that I ran the below command for build:

```
run-script build -- --output-path=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory
```

This fixed the issue I was facing.